# VS 2015 on development VS 2013 on CI

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2015, teamcity-8.0

I'm facing situation where team develops solution using VS 2015 on local machines and CI (in this case TeamCity) is configured to use VS 2013 to build solution and later create installation pack with compiled app. TeamCity version is 8.1 and VS 2015 is not supported. As an implication MSBuild uses two different toolset versions on CI on local machines. I'm not sure if that's the right way to create software.

What's your experiences? Is there something you can suggest? Or do you think it's safe to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

From a technical standpoint, as long as they aren't using features that don't require MSBuild 14.0, you should be fine targeting NetFX45.

When they need those features, you'll need to upgrade TeamCity as well as the VS instance on the build agent.